# Crm 2011 - Is there a way to know if the "context / service" is on a plugin or a 3th party application?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a common DLL file with a global methods that some of them are relevant for a **plugins only**, for ex: a methods that deals with Context.MessageName, Context.Stage, ... and other methods that can be called from 3th party apps too.

And I want to hide those not relevant methods in the 3th party apps or just check if I'm not in a plugin so I'll throw an exception.

For that, I need a way to know if the running lines of code are from a plugin or 3th party applications.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are thinking about this from the wrong perspective.  If a piece of code has access to your method, and can call the method with the correct Context parameter, then by definition shouldn't the method be relevant for that code?

If this isn't the case, then more information is required.